# Formatting text in tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want "\(category.questionCount) Questions" text to be aligned right, while
"\(category.categoryName)  >  \(category.subCategoryName)" text to be aligned left.

NOTE: In this case, not sure left alignment is necessary.

```
cell.titleL?.text = "\(category.categoryName)  >  \(category.subCategoryName) \(category.questionCount) Questions"
```

[image]

Comment: You should be using two labels, not one.

Comment: @rmaddy ok. Will try with that.

Comment: @rmaddy By the way, how can I get long text shown as ... ? Something like in the last cell row.

Comment: That's the standard behavior when the text is too long to fit in the label.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it also possible to do horizontal scrolling on the text?

Comment: That's a completely separate question. Do some searching. If you can't find an answer, post a new question specific to that question. Be sure you provide details about what you have tried and what help you need.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using two labels, not one. If a text is too long, you can set `firstLabel.numberOfLines=0`, set secondLabel alignment to right.

Comment: yea, he also suggests using two labels.